# How to display an alert in page based interface on WatchOS?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos, wkinterfacecontroller

My watch app has a page based interface where I don’t really know what InterfaceController is currently on the screen (it could be 1 of 4), however I need to pop an alert no matter what screen the app is on.  How can I present an alert given I don't know necessarily which InterfaceController is "current?"  The code below will only run if the user has navigated to this InterfaceController.  If the user isn't on that page, then I see this error in the console `2019-09-22 15:42:01.597663-0400 Watch Extension[501:526217] Warning: Attempt to present <PUICAlertSheetController: 0x18158c00> on <SPInterfaceViewController: 0x1795e800> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

```
extension WorkoutControlsInterfaceController: WorkoutEndedDelegate {
    func timerEndedCheckToSeeIfWorkoutEnded(_ manager: WorkoutManager) {
        let endWorkoutAction = WKAlertAction(title: "End Workout", style: .default, handler: {
            print("User has selected to end the workout")
            self.workoutManager?.stopWorkout()

        })
        let cancelAction = WKAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {

        })
        self.becomeCurrentPage()
        self.presentAlert(withTitle: "Workout Ended?", message: "It looks like your workout may have ended?", preferredStyle: .alert, actions: [endWorkoutAction, cancelAction])
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `visibileInterfaceController` property from the shared `WKExtesion` object;

```
extension WorkoutControlsInterfaceController: WorkoutEndedDelegate {
    func timerEndedCheckToSeeIfWorkoutEnded(_ manager: WorkoutManager) {
        let endWorkoutAction = WKAlertAction(title: "End Workout", style: .default, handler: {
            print("User has selected to end the workout")
            self.workoutManager?.stopWorkout()

        })
        let cancelAction = WKAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {

        })

        WKExtension.shared().visibleInterfaceController?.presentAlert(withTitle: "Workout Ended?", message: "It looks like your workout may have ended?", preferredStyle: .alert, actions: [endWorkoutAction, cancelAction])
    }


}
```